# Получить тип присоединенного BT устройства

Tags: android, bluetooth

Получаю список присоединенных Bluetooth-устройств к смартфону с помощью следующего кода:

```
private void getPairedDevices() {
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if (pairedDevice.size() > 0) {
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevice) {
            boolean turn = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < ListPaired.size(); ++i) {
                if (ListPaired.get(i).equals(device.getName())) {
                    turn = true;
                }
            }
            if (!turn) {
                ListPaired.add(device.getName());
                ListPairedBTDevices.add(device);
            }
            turn = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Как в полученном списке определить тип подключенного устройства (другой смартфон, принтер и т.п.)

Comment: Это называется лень 99 LVL. Google -> android bluetoothDevice get type -> первая ссылка. Вы издеваетесь?

Comment: И все операции с turn  можно заменить на 1 строчку - ListPaired.contains(device.getName())

Answer (score 1):

То, что Вы хотите получить, называется не тип (который classic, le, или dual), а класс (`Bluetooth class of device`): 
     `BluetoothClass class = device.getBluetoothClass();`
Подробности смотрите в `BluetoothClass`.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваше экспертное мнение по теме вопроса.